# Include a custom Jquery plugin in Backbone + Requirejs using shim

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, backbone.js, requirejs, backbone-views

I have a project in backbone and I am using require.js to modularize the code.

my main.js looks like this:

```
require.config({
    paths:{
        jquery:'../../../../core/js/external/jquery/jquery-1.8.2',
        underscore:'../../../../core/js/external/underscore/underscore',
        backbone:'../../../../core/js/external/backbone/backbone',
        text:'../../../../core/js/external/require/text',
        backbone_paginate:'../../../../core/js/external/backbone/backbone.pagination',
        'jquery.sprites':'../../../../core/js/sprites',
        'jquery.sprite_util':'../../../../core/js/util/spriteUtil'


    },
    shim:{
        'backbone':{
            deps:['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports:'Backbone'
        },
        'underscore':{
            exports:'_'
        },
        'jquery.blades':{
            deps:['jquery']
        },

        'jquery.sprites':{
            deps:['jquery']
        },
        'jquery.sprite_util':{
            deps:['jquery.sprites']
        }
    }
    }
});
require(['../app'], function (AppView) {
    "use strict";
    new AppView();
});
```

So, here the jquery.sprites and jquery.utils are the plugins that I need to use without including them in my Views. Currently I have to include them everywhere wherever they are being used. For exaample:

```
define([
  'jquery',
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'views/SimpleNamedObjectView',
  'jquery.sprites',
  'jquery.sprite_util',


], function($, _, Backbone, SimpleNamedObjectView){
  "use strict";
```

Is there a way where I can access the jquery.sprites and jquery.sprite_util without including them in every view? Can it become global for all the views from main.js so that I can use the functions of these plugins without including them in all the views?
For example this.$el.getSprites(); (where the getSprites is a method of jquery.sprites)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once they're loaded, as they're "shimmed", they're going to be available globally.

So you could call them as dependencies in your bootstrapping `require` call inside `main.js`. This would work.

**But**! That's completely against the philosophy of Require.js and AMD. Each module should declare all their dependencies so they can all be loaded individually and work as is. This would also allow for easier unit testing.

So, yes you can, but you **really shouldn't do this**.

Comment: I agree to what you are saying. But say for example I have downloaded a jquery plugin like Datepicker and I want it to be global all over my application since many views would use that plugin, don't you think it would be a good idea to make it global?

Comment: No, because if you don't keep track of dependencies in each modules, then you can break something if you decide to remove it, or you may not when a dependencies is not used anymore. In all case, it would work global, but it'll be hard to scale your app in the future (with other new, other, developpers and your future self).